# Сессии + Apache + PHP

Tags: apache, nginx, php, сессия

Такая проблема, есть тестовый контур, на нем один и тот же проект работает под Apache и ngnix. На nginx с сессиями все нормально, на apache непонятные проблемы - чего-то не хватает в окружении. Вообщем ни одна сессия не работает правильно, вроде бы и записывается, но при следующей загрузке скрипта все пропадает... я не могу конкретно объяснить что не работает. Если я правильно понял, то сессии дублируются в базу. В основе zend framework 1, проект достаточно большой, поэтому конкретное место в коде я выложить не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста заставить сессии работать с Apache? Проблема 100% в окружении, куда можно посмотреть, что проверить?

Comment: проект работает на nginx?

Comment: Продакшн версия на ngnix, на тестовом контуре комбинирую оба, на машине разработки - OpenSuse + apache2

Comment: nginx - работает у вас как веб сервер или как прокси сервер например на php-fpm? Просто как веб-сервер я встречал всего одну статью как это сделать, но что то одобреных отзывово к ней я не встречал.

Comment: php-fpm есть (честно говоря, с nginx раньше не работал, плохо ориентируюсь, вся система настраивалась не мной)

Comment: тогда пинайте сис. админа. пусть конфиг для php-fpm правит.

Comment: Ну зачем же его пинать? ))
nginx как раз работает как надо. А у меня на машине разработки стоит к сожалению apache, и переставить я его не могу... а сессии некорректно работают именно здесь (на машине разработки)
Сравнивал настройки php.ini увы! Не помогает.

Comment: Посмотрите конфиг зенда. Там вроде тоже есть настройки сессиий. Может они указывают на некорректный путь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была из-за того, что где-то в проекте на папку с кэшем не было прав. Решилось так:

```
chmod 777 -R
```